# Create row in table with 3 columns

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a table with a row and three columns and with select and input tags.

like this:

```js
<script>
function myaddorder(){
  
     //make field products
 var selectnew = document.createElement("SELECT");
 //make field style
 var selectnew2 = document.createElement("SELECT");
 //make field numbers
 var selectnew3 = document.createElement("INPUT");
 
 
 var optprt1 = document.createElement("option");
 var optprt2 = document.createElement("option");
 optprt1.text = "pro1";
 optprt2.text = "pro2";
 selectnew.add(optprt1);
 selectnew.add(optprt2);
 
 var optst1 = document.createElement("option");
 var optst2 = document.createElement("option");
 optst1.text = "stlye1";
 optst2.text = "stlye2";
 selectnew2.add(optst1);
 selectnew2.add(optst2);
 
 selectnew.setAttribute("id" , "seletpro");
 selectnew2.setAttribute("id" , "selectstyle");
 selectnew3.setAttribute("id" , "selectnum");
 
 
 
 
 document.body.appendChild(selectnew);
 document.body.appendChild(selectnew2);
 document.body.appendChild(selectnew3);
 
 


 
}
 function mydelorder() {
    document.getElementById("seletpro").remove();
 document.getElementById("selectstyle").remove();
 document.getElementById("selectnum").remove();
}
</script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div1">
<table id="formorder">
 <tr>
     <td>
      <select id="seletpro">
             <option value="pro">pro</option>
             <option value="pro1">pro1</option>
             <option value="pro2">pro2</option>
             <option value="pro3">pro3</option>
   </select>
            
     </td>
     <td>
      <select id="selectstyle">
             <option value="stlye1">stlye1</option>
              <option value="stlye2">stlye2</option>
          </select>
           
     </td>
     <td><input id="selectnum"><span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    
<button onclick="myaddorder()">+</button>
<button onclick="mydelorder()">-</button>
<script>
function myaddorder(){
  
     //make field products
 var selectnew = document.createElement("SELECT");
 //make field style
 var selectnew2 = document.createElement("SELECT");
 //make field numbers
 var selectnew3 = document.createElement("INPUT");
 
 
 var optprt1 = document.createElement("option");
 var optprt2 = document.createElement("option");
 optprt1.text = "pro1";
 optprt2.text = "pro2";
 selectnew.add(optprt1);
 selectnew.add(optprt2);
 
 var optst1 = document.createElement("option");
 var optst2 = document.createElement("option");
 optst1.text = "stlye1";
 optst2.text = "stlye2";
 selectnew2.add(optst1);
 selectnew2.add(optst2);
 
 selectnew.setAttribute("id" , "seletpro");
 selectnew2.setAttribute("id" , "selectstyle");
 selectnew3.setAttribute("id" , "selectnum");
 
 
 
 
 document.body.appendChild(selectnew);
 document.body.appendChild(selectnew2);
 document.body.appendChild(selectnew3);
 
 


 
}
 function mydelorder() {
    document.getElementById("seletpro").remove();
 document.getElementById("selectstyle").remove();
 document.getElementById("selectnum").remove();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I click plus button i don't want to show in a body. I want that create a row and show to inside the columns. And when I press the minus button do it vice versa.

can you help me?

Comment: *"I don't want to show in body"* then why are you doing `document.body.appendChild(selectnew)`? First create a `<tr>` element, then three `<td>` elements inside it, and append your elements to each of them. Finally, append the `<tr>` to the table.

Answer (score 1):

For the adding part, you need to Build a row that you can add to the table.
So you should replace

```
document.body.appendChild(selectnew);
document.body.appendChild(selectnew2);
document.body.appendChild(selectnew3);
```

By something like this :

```
// Create the cells of the new row   
var td1 = document.createElement("td");
var td2 = document.createElement("td");
var td3 = document.createElement("td");

// Add fields to those cells
td1.appendChild(selectnew);
td2.appendChild(selectnew2);
td3.appendChild(selectnew3);

// Create the row itself
tr = document.createElement("tr");

// Add cells to the row
tr.appendChild(td1);
tr.appendChild(td2);
tr.appendChild(td3);

// Get the table
tab  = document.getElementById("formorder");

// Add the row to the table
tab.appendChild(tr);
```

The removing part seems to work except that it removes elements from the top of the table. You can get the last element by doing

```
document.getElementById("formorder").lastChild;
```

Also, elements should not have the same "id" property. You can use "class" instead.